# "Your edit can only be saved" notification bar on review items persists to the next review

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, notification-bar, improve-edit

I was reviewing suggested edits on Ask Ubuntu, and as I improved [an edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/147182) (keeping the "helpful" box checked, in case that matters), I was informed that the post had been edited.

[image: Notification bar saying: This post has been edited 1 time sincce you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.]

In this case, it meant that the suggested edit had been approved (not that it had been improved by another user while I was composing my improvements, which also can happen).

I submitted my review, and my edit was accepted. But **the bar telling me that the post was edited persisted**.

This should probably be considered a bug, because:

- After the edit is submitted successfully, the reviewer doesn't need to know what the bar is saying, even if somehow they didn't read it already.
- Reviewers will likely be confused into thinking the bar might pertain to their next review item (over which it appears). At minimum, the bar is meaningless for the next review item.

This occurred in Google Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m on Windows 8 (running in desktop mode, *not* RT mode / "Windows 8 mode"). In case that matters.